# Why when casting in inline with assign a value it compiles?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

This is my `Example` code

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){


        short s = 100;
        byte b = s;         // this is compile time error because of no casting

        byte z = (short)25.12; // why this happens 

        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(((Object)z).getClass());

    }
}
```

please forgive for me as i just begin to learn java.
can you please tell me this problem in technically.

Comment: Because a static compiler doesn't know the `s` value at comile time, but It knows `(short)25.12` value at comile time.

Comment: clear and solid question. but must duplicate.

Comment: `byte z = (short)25.12;` works for the same reason that `byte z = 25;` would (the latter is `int` assigned to `byte`)

Answer (score 2):

1. Your this line `byte b = s;` gives error because you can't assign bigger data type **short(2 bytes)** to smaller data type **byte(1 byte)**. That is why it is giving you compile time error.
2. Now coming to this line `byte z = (short)25.12;` lets break it down. `25.2` is by default **double** but when you typecast it using **(short)** it becomes `25` which is an **integral** literal. Now compiler will check whether 25 can be stored in byte or not. And since `5` is between **-128 and 127** i.e. the range of byte it won't give any compile time error. But if you give any value out of the range of byte it will give error. Eg: `byte z = (short)128.12;`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn’t run your source code or analyze its logic.  The compiler merely creates bytecode from each line of your source code.

When the compiler sees `byte b = s;`, it just tries to generate code that assigns the value of `b`.  It doesn’t look back through your code to see what other instructions may have affected the value of `s`.

It only knows that on that line of code, you are trying to set an 8-bit value (a byte) to an unknown 16-bit value (a short).  When the compiler is looking at this line of code, it does not consider any previous lines, so it doesn’t care about the prior assignment;  it treats `s` as an unknown 16-bit value.  That unknown value might or might not be something that fits in 8 bits.

On the other hand, `byte z = (short)25.12;` is safe because the compiler doesn’t need to look at any other instructions to know that 25 can fit into 8 bits.  It doesn’t matter that you have cast it to a `short`.  What matters is that implicitly casting it to `byte` will not lose any information.

This would be true for `(int) 25` as well.  In all cases, 25 will fit in 8 bits without losing information.

Comment: @JavaZonic Oops, you’re right, apparently an implicit conversion from `long` is not permitted.  Only `int` and smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting a bigger datatype to a smaller one is not implicit because it can result in an incorrect conversion (loss of data).

```
         byte b = s;
```

That's why the above line wont't compile because s is of type short (2 bytes) and b is of type byte (1 byte). Hence you need to typecast it explicitly

```
         byte b = (byte)s;
```

Comment: this is unrelated answer what i asked.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look this article: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-data-types
You getting errors, because:

**short** takes **16 bit**(2 byte)

**byte** takes **8 bit** (1 byte)

You can't put 16 bits,  in to 8 bits.